# Profanity Filter Lua

Tags: string, lua, string-matching, lua-table

so i'm mediocre at lua, but i was just playing around with this

```
local profanitywords = {"fuck", "shit", "ass"} -- a small list
local input = io.read()

for i,v in ipairs (profanitywords) do
   if string.find(input:lower(), v) then
      print("Profanity")
   else
       print("Not Profanity")
   end
end
```

but what i get in the output is this:

[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5R3D.png)
also, i'm using zerobrane studios

and sometimes when i enter different things, it doesn't work at all. help?

Comment: What output do you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
local profanity
for i,v in ipairs (profanitywords) do
   if string.find(input:lower(), v) then
      profanity = true
      break
   end
end

if profanity then
    print("Profanity")
else
    print("Not Profanity")
end
```